# codeigniter multiple join conditions on same table

Tags: sql, codeigniter, join

Basically i want to join a table where a col in table A matches a col in table B and where a col in table B is equal to 0.  I am using codeigniters active record class.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$this->db->join('B', 'aCol = bCol AND bOtherCol = 0');
$this->db->get('A');
```

Optionally, a third argument can be specified for the `join` method to indicate whether a left or right join should be performed. For example, to perform a left join:

```
$this->db->join('B', 'aCol = bCol AND bOtherCol = 0', 'left');
```

Comment: You can actually mark the question as solved by clicking on the "V" sign next to the answer.